# C# routing event from multiple objects thru one event

Tags: c#, events

So I'm using C# 3.0, and I'm trying to accomplish some specific form of event routing.

```
public class A
{ 
  public delegate void FooDel(string blah);
  public Event FooDel FooHandler;

  //...some code that eventually raises FooHandler event
}

public class B
{
  public A a = new A(); 

  //...some code that calls functions on "a" that might cause
  //FooHandler event to be raised
}

public class C
{
  private List<B> MyListofBs = new List<B>();

  //...code that causes instances of B to be added to the list
  //and calls functions on those B instances that might get A.FooHandler raised

  public Event A.FooDel FooHandler;
}
```

What I'm trying to figure out is how to route all `A.FooHandler` event firings of instances of A to the one event `C.FooHandler`. So that if someone registers to `C.FooHandler` they would really be getting events raised by any of the instances of A contained by instances of B in the list.

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the example code you have provided, you cannot do what you want. Since you have made `A` private within `B`, you are sealing off access to the `A` instance from any code outside of the `B` class (which includes the `C` class).

You must somehow make your `A` instance publicly accessible so that the methods within `C` can access it through `B` in order to subscribe and de-subscribe to the event contained within `A`.

---

**Edit:** Assuming B.a was public, the easiest thing to do since `C.MyListofBs` is private, is to create your own Add/Remove methods which also subscribe and de-subscribe to the event you want within A, like so.

I also took the liberty of removing your delegate in favor of the much cleaner [`Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx) class.

```
public class A
{ 
    public Event Action<string> FooHandler;

    //...some code that eventually raises FooHandler event
}

public class B
{
    public A a = new A();

    //...some code that calls functions on "a" that might cause
    //FooHandler event to be raised
}

public class C
{
    private List<B> MyListofBs = new List<B>();

    //...code that causes instances of B to be added to the list
    //and calls functions on those B instances that might get A.FooHandler raised

    public void Add(B item)
    {
        MyListofBs.Add(item);
        item.a.FooHandler += EventAction;
    }

    public void Remove(B item)
    {
        item.a.FooHandler -= EventAction;
        MyListofBs.Remove(item);
    }

    private void EventAction(string s)
    {
        // This is invoked when "A.FooHandler" is raised for any 
        // item inside the MyListofBs collection.
    }
}
```

---

**Edit:** And if you want a relay event in `C`, do this:

```
public class C
{
    private List<B> MyListofBs = new List<B>();

    public event Action<string> RelayEvent;

    //...code that causes instances of B to be added to the list
    //and calls functions on those B instances that might get A.FooHandler raised

    public void Add(B item)
    {
        MyListofBs.Add(item);
        item.a.FooHandler += EventAction;
    }

    public void Remove(B item)
    {
        item.a.FooHandler -= EventAction;
        MyListofBs.Remove(item);
    }

    private void EventAction(string s)
    {
        if(RelayEvent != null)
        {
            RelayEvent(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok say "a" in B was public.

Comment: But now there is no event in C i can subscribe to, which is my aim.

Comment: It's simple, just add the event and invoke it. See my latest edit.

Comment: Ah, I had though of something like that, but wondered if there was a direct routing way like defining in some special way the add and remove of the C.RelayEvent.

Comment: If you're feeling adventurous you could decompile some of the WPF libraries and figure out how Microsoft handles its tunneling/bubbling routed events.

Comment: Hmm if i wanted to keep the instance of A in b private, i guess I could relay the event with a proxy event in B like: public event FooHandler { add { a.FooHandler += value; } remove { a.FooHandler -= value; }

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe to your B.foohandler events

```
Foreach(var item in MyListofBs) 
{

      Item.fooHandler += new EventHandler(CEventHandler) 
}
   //each time your Events are called you reroute it with C.EventHandler 
Private CEventHandler(string blah) 
{    
    If(FooHanler!=null)
       FooHanler(); 
}
```

Go over the following example [Events Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Where would this foreach go? Does that happen after all Bs are added to the list in C? What is EventHandler, where is that defined?

Comment: Yes you subscribe either after all the list is created or after each item is added